# Count multiple values in Same Cell, within whole Row in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'd like to create a formula to look at a column in excel and count if there is an entry, such as D48 for example. So it will go through and count all the "D48" entries throughout the column, even if it is separated by commas. So a cell containing "D48, D48" or "D48, D48, D48" will all be counted.

I have a working formula right now, but it takes blank cells and assigns a value of -1. How can I avoid this? Is there a more efficient way to write this formula?

```
Function CountText(sLookFor As String, rSearchRange As Range) As Long

Dim cel As Range

For Each cel In rSearchRange
    CountText = CountText + UBound(Split(cel.Value, sLookFor))
Next cel

End Function
```

but here's the code that worked based on responses below (problem solved!!!)

```
Function CountText(sLookFor As String, rSearchRange As Range) As Long
    Dim cel As Range

    For Each cel In rSearchRange

    If cel = "" Then

    Else
        CountText = CountText + UBound(Split(cel.Value, sLookFor))
    End If
Next cel

End Function
```

Comment: Is `D48` literal or does it mean the text or number (or error) value in row 48, column 4?

Comment: @Jeeped D48 is the content within a cell that I'd like to search for in a different excel tab.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
For Each cel In rSearchRange
    if cel = "" then
        next cel
    else
        CountText = CountText + UBound(Split(cel.Value, sLookFor))
    end if
Next cel
```

or

```
For Each cel In rSearchRange
    if cel <> "" then
        CountText = CountText + UBound(Split(cel.Value, sLookFor))
    end if
Next cel
```

Comment: Thanks  I'm getting a Next without For error for this

Comment: I'm assuming it's the next cel inside the if statement

Comment: Great.  Did you have to edit the example for it to work?

Comment: Yes, I had to edit the example slightly, you can see it in my edited original post. My only issue is that this makes my worksheet operate very, very slowly! Do you have any idea how to make this more efficient/ run quicker?

Comment: I doubt that the "If" is the culprit in slowing your code down.  I edited the answer to provide another way to do the same thing.

Comment: To clarify, I have this formula working in about 300+ cells. If I only have the formula working in one cell, it is pretty quick. But if I make a change to any of the cells that this formula looks at (they all look at the column F:F on a different sheet) then it has to calculate for 3 minutes, and I can't do anything until it finishes. I tried the new code you recommended and it is not a marked improvement in speed

Comment: Actually, I got it to work. I just restricted it from F:F to F5:F1502. It was just looking through way too many cells.

Answer (score 0):

Track the number of instances of your 'delimiter' by retrieving the length of the string minus the retrieving the length of the string without the delimiliter divided by the length of the delimiter.

```
Function CountText(sLookFor As String, rSearchRange As Range) As Long
    Dim cel As Range
    For Each cel In rSearchRange
        CountText = (Len(cel.Value) - Len(Replace(cel.Value, sLookFor, vbNullString))) / Len(sLookFor)
    Next cel
End Function
```

The replace function is currently case-sensitive but can be altered to case-insensitive.

Comment: Thanks for the response- I'm not sure exactly what is going on with this one, but I'm getting a "0" result for all of the search results, no matter how many there actually are.